# how to create the data model for this { "words":[3,4,5] } json in kotlin

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, datamodel

I was trying to write a data model to send a JSON to the API and delete some fields
the JSON should contain the id of some words and it should look exactly like this :

```
{
"words":[3,4,5]
}
```

as I know and also as the https://jsonformatter.org/ said the data class should be something like the following piece of code:

```
data class words(var id: List<Int>)
```

but the problem is when I pass the data to it and toast it to see if it's a valid JSON request for the server the output will be this :

```
words(id=[1,2,4,5])
```

and it's not what it should be.
as I said I need this :

```
{
"words":[3,4,5]
}
```

Comment: First, however you are creating your `Toast` is not generating JSON. Second, your property name needs to be `words`, not `id`.

Comment: what should be the data class name?

Comment: and if toasting is not a good way to make sure if final json is what i need so how can i test it?

Comment: i need to find out what do i pass to the retrofit

Comment: "what should be the data class name?" -- it can be whatever you want. "and if toasting is not a good way to make sure if final json is what i need so how can i test it? " -- the problem is not the `Toast`. The problem is that you appear to be just calling `toString()` on the object. `toString()` does not create JSON, XML, CSV, HTML, etc. If you have configured Retrofit properly, it will convert your object to JSON for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work.

```
data class AnyNameYouWant(val words: List<Int>)
```

I think the name of the data class really doesn't matter as it would finally represent the `{  }` object syntax of json.

Looking in the comments, I think it's better to use some logging library like [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber). If you are using **Retrofit** then use can also use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` and set the level to `Body` that will print the body of the response in the logcat.